# Can I bypass the 20 Item Limit for Statc Cascading Context Menus in Windows (Registry keys/subkeys)

Tags: windows, imagemagick, registry, contextmenu, limit

I'm creating a detailed static cascading context menu for ImageMagick in Windows...

Everything seemed to be working well functionality-wise until I passed 20 items with the context menu. After that, clicking on commands stopped functioning properly and items disappeared. (I know its not a formatting issue because I can bring them back by deleting higher up items) There was plenty of space on my screen with my organization scheme... They only disappeared because of an unneeded limit!

Does anybody know if there is a way to increase this limit in context-menu size? To be clear, the 20 items limit is accumulating for anything below the root level :( ...

The following comes out to be 6 items ...

Right-Click -> ImageMagick -> convert -> item1,item2

Right-Click -> ImageMagick -> mogrify -> item3,item4

Please don't answer saying that its too cluttered/shouldn't be done, the 20 items so far looked perfectly fine and I'd only need about 60 for this to be complete.

If the limit can't be increased, do you know if this limit also exists with dynamic shell-extension DLLs?

Comment: I have recently hit this annoying limit myself. Were you able to find a solution?

Comment: Also looking for a solution here!

Comment: Try the solution of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42213100/is-there-a-way-to-get-past-the-16-entry-limit-for-context-menus

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to get past the 16 entry limit for context menus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42213100/is-there-a-way-to-get-past-the-16-entry-limit-for-context-menus)