# Is there a maximum right click context menu items limit?

Tags: windows, registry, contextmenu

I'm making a custom right click submenu (in Windows registry) using `SubCommands`, but after adding more options to it, some last options disappeared. Is there a maximum amount of items that are allowed? If so, is there a way to workaround? I'm on Windows 7. When I go to the registry, all the SubCommands are saved in the string value.

Comment: Please specify language and technologies you're using

Comment: Using a registry file:

`[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\VDBProjectTools]
"MUIVerb"="Finish Project"
"SubCommands"="1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;10;11;12;13;14;15;etc"
"Position"=-`

There seems to be a limit of `SubCommands`.

Comment: Try the solution of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42213100/is-there-a-way-to-get-past-the-16-entry-limit-for-context-menus

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes! there's a limit of 16 entries for each context menu entry, including submenus and any entry inside of them.. If I'm not mistaken this limit exists since the dawn of Windows, at least as far back as Windows 95. At the time, leaving that feature without any limit could negatively impact system performance. This limit however, doesn't seem to apply to COM shell extensions, so there might be a solution around. I think it's best to organize and be more selective on what's included in the context menu.

Comment: I can confirm that this 16-entries-including-all-nested-entries limit exists (in Windows 7)
Just spent/wasted 2 hours in debugging and tweaking why the newly added entries don't show up or don't work.

Does anyone know of a **generic** COM Shell extension that can be configured to show/exec the commands you like, in a freely user defined tree structure?

Comment: @lidqy there are a few options. You should try out "KuShellExtension" which is a DLL you register and dinamically loads context menu entries from a config file. Be aware that the last version is from 2010, so there might be some strange behavior on Windows 10. But it is a complete solution that allows for more than 16 context menu entries for files or folders. If you decide to use it try to be conservative. After many edits you should restart explorer.exe to clear up memory, and once you finish your configuration you should restart the system.