# Windows right click context menu items number limit

Tags: windows, registry, contextmenu

I follow this link from Microsoft to create Windows 10 context menu.

How to Create Cascading Menus with the SubCommands Registry Entry:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/shell/how-to--create-cascading-menus-with-the-subcommands-registry-entry

However, I found if items in the context menu are more than a certain number.
Windows only show part of the context menu items.

If I have a structure like this, it will end up showing the submenu1 and submenu2.
If you have even more items for each submenu, it will only show submenu1.

My Context Menu

- Submenu1

  - Items1
  - Items2
  - Items3
  - ...
- Submenu2

  - Items1
  - Items2
  - Items3
  - ...
- Submenu3

  - Items1
  - Items2
  - Items3
  - ...

Also found similar questions but no answers for them too:

[maximum right click context menu items limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48625223/maximum-right-click-context-menu-items-limit)

[Can I bypass the 20 Item Limit for Statc Cascading Context Menus in Windows (Registry keys/subkeys)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25799022/can-i-bypass-the-20-item-limit-for-statc-cascading-context-menus-in-windows-reg)

Comment: Try the solution of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42213100/is-there-a-way-to-get-past-the-16-entry-limit-for-context-menus

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to get past the 16 entry limit for context menus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42213100/is-there-a-way-to-get-past-the-16-entry-limit-for-context-menus)